# Using slicers on a multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, slice

I've got a dataframe of the form:

```
Contract  Date      
201501    2014-04-29    1416.0
          2014-04-30    1431.1
          2014-05-01    1430.6
          2014-05-02    1443.9
          2014-05-05    1451.6
          2014-05-06    1461.4
          2014-05-07    1456.0
          2014-05-08    1441.1
          2014-05-09    1437.8
          2014-05-12    1445.2
          2014-05-13    1458.2
          2014-05-14    1487.6
          2014-05-15    1477.6
          2014-05-16    1467.9
          2014-05-19    1484.9
          2014-05-20    1470.5
          2014-05-21    1476.9
          2014-05-22    1490.0
          2014-05-23    1473.3
          2014-05-27    1462.5
          2014-05-28    1456.3
          2014-05-29    1460.5
201507    2014-05-30    1463.5
          2014-06-02    1447.5
          2014-06-03    1444.4
          2014-06-04    1444.7
          2014-06-05    1455.9
          2014-06-06    1464.0
```

Where Contract & Date are indices of type `int` and `datetime64` respectively.

What I want is to select a date range. It works by doing:

```
df.reset_index('Contract', drop=True).loc['2014-09']
```

But I hate this as it loses the index/is not very pleasant (I have to do a lot of these).

I think I should be able to do it like this:

```
df.loc[:,'2014-09']
```

to bring back all of September 2014's data. In reality, this doesn't work. I can only select a single day by doing:

```
df.loc[:,'2014-09-02']
```

Why doesn't my multi-index slicer work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas needs you to be explicit about whether you're selecting columns or sub-levels of a hierarchical index. In this case, `df.loc[:,'2014-09']` fails because pandas tries to get all rows and then look for a column labelled `'2014-09'` (which doesn't exist).

Instead, you need to give both levels of the multi-index *and* the column labels/slice.

To select all of the May 2014 data from your example you could write:

```
>>> df.loc[(slice(None), '2014-05'), :]                            
Contract Date              
201501   2014-05-01  1430.6
         2014-05-02  1443.9
         2014-05-05  1451.6
         2014-05-06  1461.4
         2014-05-07  1456.0
         2014-05-08  1441.1
         2014-05-09  1437.8
         2014-05-12  1445.2
         2014-05-13  1458.2
         2014-05-14  1487.6
         2014-05-15  1477.6
         2014-05-16  1467.9
         2014-05-19  1484.9
         2014-05-20  1470.5
         2014-05-21  1476.9
         2014-05-22  1490.0
         2014-05-23  1473.3
         2014-05-27  1462.5
         2014-05-28  1456.3
         2014-05-29  1460.5
201507   2014-05-30  1463.5
```

Here `[(slice(None), '2014-05'), :]` translates to a slice of `[:, '2014-05']` for the rows and `[:]` for the columns.

The `pd.IndexSlice` object was introduced to make these slice semantics a little easier:

```
>>> idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> df.loc[idx[:, '2014-05'], :]
# same slice of DataFrame
```

Comment: Does this definitely work? As I'm trying this, it seems to just return all data, rather than the respective slice (so it will work in your example with the limited data set, but not on my expanded data set).

Comment: @cjm2671, can you try to reproduce it using your sample data set?

Comment: @cjm2671: it should work; I'm not sure how all of the rows would be returned unless you *slice* in the second level too, using an earlier date, e.g. `df.loc[idx[:, '2013-05':], :]`. As MaxU suggests, perhaps you could reproduce this problem on a smaller data set so that we could investigate further?

Comment: @ajcr, do you know why `df.loc[(slice(None), '2014-05'), :]` works and `df.ix[(slice(None), '2014-05'), :]` doesn't work?

Comment: OK, I did get it to work. I made a mistake above- it was a pd.Series with a multi-index, not a DataFrame. When I applied to_frame(), it worked. Can I ask, why would this not work on a Series?

Comment: Ah ok, no problem. I *think* the indexer classes (`loc`, `iloc`, etc.) don't differentiate between a Series and DataFrame themselves, so if you have a Series and write `s.loc[:,'2014-09']` it will still try to look for `'2014-09'` on axis 1, even though there is no axis 1 (column labels).

Comment: @MaxU: I'm sure not sure why that is to be honest. From a design view, perhaps `ix` should be made to work or at least produce a more helpful error message when given a multi-index slicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Indexslice` to select based on ranges for each `level` of your `MultiIndex` like so ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, '2014-05'], :]
```

to get:

```
Contract Date              
201501   2014-05-01  1430.6
         2014-05-02  1443.9
         2014-05-05  1451.6
         2014-05-06  1461.4
         2014-05-07  1456.0
         2014-05-08  1441.1
         2014-05-09  1437.8
         2014-05-12  1445.2
         2014-05-13  1458.2
         2014-05-14  1487.6
         2014-05-15  1477.6
         2014-05-16  1467.9
         2014-05-19  1484.9
         2014-05-20  1470.5
         2014-05-21  1476.9
         2014-05-22  1490.0
         2014-05-23  1473.3
         2014-05-27  1462.5
         2014-05-28  1456.3
         2014-05-29  1460.5
201507   2014-05-30  1463.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.dt accessor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) to extract all values of the month September as follows:

```
df.loc[(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.month == 9)]
```

Timing constraints:

```
timeit df.loc[(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.month == 5)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 796 µs per loop
```